# Place in StackExchange To Ask About Ruby on Rails Development?

Tags: discussion

Hello,

Where would be the best place to ask about Ruby on Rails web development on the Stack Exchange network? I searched around on the SE /sites homepage and couldn't find one that was related to it. Webmasters and webapps are obviously not suited for such a question. Programmers... I'm not so sure.

Comment: You've found the right place. This is the place where we deal with questions involving code. Fire away!

Comment: ask on stackoverflow and tag properly.

Comment: Definitely StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

I would say Stack Overflow—but like the comments say, make sure you tag it properly.

If it doesn't belong there and gets moved? Well, good try!

Comment: Migrated from SO to meta to be told that the place is SO?!

Comment: @David Yes put this question is not about programming.

Comment: @user I know I agree with you. You can see that from my comment to the question which was written when the Q originally landed at SO. I'd happily migrate it back but I've got no rep here! It should have been closed as not a real question, not migrated, and some comments left for the inquisitor.

Comment: @David No, everything happened as it should've. This question should've been asked on Meta, so it was migrated here. Future questions that are actually about RoR development will be posted on SO, where they belong.